# Running React Native application using Expo

Tags: android, react-native

[Tutorial](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#running-your-react-native-application) says:

*Install the Expo client app on your iOS or Android phone and connect to the same wireless network as your computer. On Android, use the Expo app to scan the QR code from your terminal to open your project. On iOS, follow on-screen instructions to get a link.*

But my computer doesn't have Wi-Fi Internet, it has wire internet connection, but my phone (Android) is using Wi-Fi Internet connection. The network is the same with the same IPv4 address. Is it possible to run app in Expo on these conditions?

When I am trying to scan QR-code, I got: *Something went wrong. Could not load exp://... Network response timed out.*

Comment: There's no problem at running expo over ethernet and wifi, your setup isn't a problem here. You can develop with expo by using 4g if needed. Your problem must comes from somewhere else. Did you tried to check your firewall and security rules?

Comment: @Poptocrack What exactly do I have to check?

Comment: Hard to tell like that, First thing, instead of using tunnel from expo, try to use LAN host in exp / expoXDE.
Then, if no change, try to disable completely your firewall, then your anti-virus. If it's still not working, you better go on the Expo forums where the expo community is more active.

Comment: @Poptocrack How to use LAN host in exp / expoXDE ?

Comment: for exp cli: `exp start --lan` https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/exp-cli

for expo XDE, click on the cog-wheel top left corner, under project > Host > lan